# Is it possible to login wordpress admin dashboard with defined username and password?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-login

Is there any way to login in wordpress admin dashboard with defined username and password for example

```
<?php
$username = 'my_username';
$password = 'my_password';

if ($_POST['username'] == $username && $_POST['password']){

 echo "Valid credentials";

}else{

 echo "Invalid credentials";

}
?>
```

Comment: I found this question https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/207990/is-there-a-hook-before-the-user-is-authenticated really helpful explaining the process to me, then looking up the authenticate filter help page mentioned in the last comment, it suggests you can easily hook into the authentication filter pipeline and override authentication by returning a valid user or error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible, you can do like this by first checking if the creds are valid, then set up user cookies and log them in automatically:

```
$username = 'my_username';
$password = 'my_password';

$creds = array();
$creds['user_login'] = $username;
$creds['user_password'] = $password;
$creds['remember'] = true;
$user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
if ( !is_wp_error($user) ){

  $user_id = $user->ID;
  // Log the user in
  wp_set_current_user( $user_id, $user_login );
  wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );
  // Perform any required redirections
  wp_redirect( home_url() );
  exit();

}else{

 echo "Invalid credentials";

}
```

However, make sure that this runs before headers are send to work perfectly, you may hook it to `template_redirects` for example.

Comment: Hey @ali_k Thanks for your response but I can't understand how to use it can you please describe me in more details I put this code in my theme functions.php but it says Invalid credentials

Comment: You need to put a valid username and password in the appropriate variables.

Comment: but I want to login through defined variable or constant with my given credentials in that variable or constant which are not exist in database. is it possible?

Comment: You can't login with a user that's not in the database.